# Restructuring an existing Angular app to add login

Tags: angular

We have an Angular 10 app that is currently always authenticated. The login page is part of a separate system, so it's assumed that you're logged in whenever you hit Angular (if you're not, it just redirects to that other login page). We're now converting the login page to be part of the Angular app, and I'm struggling to figure out how to properly architect this.

Some of the issues I've run into:

- Our root app module currently has a bunch of code that sets up a sidebar, header, etc. It works there because it is always present on every page, but now the login page won't follow that pattern and will be its own design.
- Many of our routes are also defined (or use lazy loading that's defined) in the root app module.
- We load some things in an APP_INITIALIZER and we have a splash screen that displays while loading, but that won't work anymore because everything in it assumes that the user is logged in.

I've come up with some possible solutions, but I'm not sure if they're the best way to do this:

- I think I need to move the code that's currently in the root app module to a separate "core" module that's only called when the user is logged in. This would essentially just be a copy/paste of the existing code, but being in a separate module avoids the router outlet problem from the first point above.
- Most routes would also need to move to this new "core" module so that they get the right `<router-outlet>`, but I'm not sure how to handle it because I don't want URLs to change. The only URL change should be the new `/login` route that I'm adding.
- I can keep the APP_INITIALIZER code but return early if the user isn't logged in and there's nothing to initialize for the login page, and I'm sure I can figure out a splash screen after the login button is clicked.

Do these solutions sound good? If so, how do I handle the routes being in the "core" module instead of the root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that you are already thinking of is a good option. Currently, your App Component's template must be having the toolbar, navigation bar, and other layout items and then, the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` right?

Steps would be:

1. Moving the overall layout(copy-pasting) that was previously contained in the App Component's template to a new "home-container.component"(or any better name as you wish).
2. App Component's template should only have the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`(and some design if needed).
3. Configuring your route to something like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path: '', component: HomeContainerComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {path: 'someroute', loadChildren: import('somefilepath').then(m -> m.SomeModule)},
            {path: 'anotherroute', component: AnotherComponent}
```

This way cleanly resolves your layout, routing, and module separation related problems. There can be tricks done with *ngIf also but this way it is simpler.

Comment: This looks great, I'll start working on this and accept the answer if I have no major issues. Thank you!